# Simple square that can change color in Interface Builder/Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, interface-builder

For an application that I am developing I need to create a grid of squares. The only relevant property they should have is the ability to change to any color (RGB).

1) What kind of object should I use? Custom?
2) Am I overlooking something? Should I, for instance, be using Core Animation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the size of your grid, but for something small (up to a few dozen squares not changing more than a few times a second, say) or prototyping, you can use `NSBox`. In IB, set Box Type to Custom and Border Type to None. You can then set the `fillColor` attribute as desired. (Mac OS X 10.5 or later)

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, you could:

1. Create an `NSView` subclass for the whole grid
2. Create an `NSView` subclass for each grid square
3. Create an `NSCell` subclass and use it with `NSMatrix`
4. Use an `NSBox` for each grid square (like Ahruman suggests)
5. Use an `NSImageView` for each grid square and and pass them an `NSImage`

I'd use option 1 or 3.

I don't think Core Animation can provide any simpler solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm going for option 3. I'm also trying Ahruman's anwser, maybe even compare them for fun's sake.